How to apply rolling_map on polars and create two columns?
See the code below, it's a stand-in for what I need. ChatGPT and perplexity aren't helpful here. In practice I can compute col1 and col2 one at a time, but it is unnecessarily slow.
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

def _compute_coef1(series):
    y = series[1:]
    x = series[:-1]

    mean_x = x.mean()
    mean_y = y.mean()

    x_centered = x - mean_x
    y_centered = y - mean_y

    den = (x_centered * x_centered).sum() or np.nan
    coef1 = (x_centered * y_centered).sum() / den

    return coef1

def _compute_coef2(series):
    y = series[1:]
    x = series[:-1]

    mean_x = x.mean()
    mean_y = y.mean()

    x_centered = x - mean_x
    y_centered = y - mean_y

    den = (x_centered * x_centered).sum() or np.nan
    coef1 = (x_centered * y_centered).sum() / den
    coef2 = mean_y - coef1 * mean_x

    return coef2

# Apply the rolling computation of AR(1) coefficients and coef2
expr1 = (
    pl.col("input_col")
    .rolling_map(_compute_coef1, window_size=10, min_periods=3)
    .alias("coef1")
)

expr2 = (
    pl.col("input_col")
    .rolling_map(_compute_coef2, window_size=10, min_periods=3)
    .alias("coef2")
)

# Testing:
df = pl.DataFrame({"input_col": [1, 1, 2, 2]})

df = df.with_columns(expr1).with_columns(expr2)


print(df)

While the code above runs and work, it is unnecessarily slow. The real version I use makes is unbearable and it spends too much memory.

A "proper" answer will likely not involve rolling_map and will depend on what the real task actually is. Perhaps you can share it?

@jqurious added a better example, anything more than this and people will say I needed a minimum working example. I don't mind not using rolling_map exactly, as long as functionally it's equivalent.

Thanks. The slowness is just from rolling_map. You should be able to use Expr.rolling or DataFrame.rolling instead and implement the functionality using Polars expressions.

The issue is just that rolling_map is a really expensive operation.

Warning: Computing custom functions is extremely slow.

Instead, you should be able to implement your functionality using the "native" rolling contexts e.g.

Expr.rolling
DataFrame.rolling

def _compute_coef1_expr(col, min_periods):
    y = col.slice(1, pl.len())
    x = col.slice(0, pl.len() - 1)

    mean_x = x.mean()
    mean_y = y.mean()

    x_centered = x - mean_x
    y_centered = y - mean_y

    den = (x_centered * x_centered).sum() 
    coef1 = (x_centered * y_centered).sum() / den

    return pl.when(pl.len() > min_periods).then(coef1)

def _compute_coef2_expr(col, min_periods):
    y = col.slice(1, pl.len())
    x = col.slice(0, pl.len() - 1)

    mean_x = x.mean()
    mean_y = y.mean()

    x_centered = x - mean_x
    y_centered = y - mean_y

    den = (x_centered * x_centered).sum() 
    coef1 = (x_centered * y_centered).sum() / den

    coef2 = mean_y - coef1 * mean_x

    return pl.when(pl.len() > min_periods).then(coef2)

.pipe() can also be used to help call the custom function.
df = pl.DataFrame({"input_col": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6]})

(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(
       pl.col.input_col.pipe(_compute_coef1_expr, min_periods=3)
         .rolling(index_column="index", period="10i")
         .alias("coef1"),
       pl.col.input_col.pipe(_compute_coef2_expr, min_periods=3)
         .rolling(index_column="index", period="10i")
         .alias("coef2")
   )
)

shape: (10, 4)
┌───────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ input_col ┆ coef1    ┆ coef2    │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ i64       ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1         ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ 1     ┆ 1         ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ 2     ┆ 2         ┆ null     ┆ null     │
│ 3     ┆ 2         ┆ 0.5      ┆ 1.0      │
│ 4     ┆ 3         ┆ 1.0      ┆ 0.5      │
│ 5     ┆ 3         ┆ 0.785714 ┆ 0.785714 │
│ 6     ┆ 3         ┆ 0.75     ┆ 0.833333 │
│ 7     ┆ 4         ┆ 0.911765 ┆ 0.617647 │
│ 8     ┆ 4         ┆ 0.857143 ┆ 0.714286 │
│ 9     ┆ 6         ┆ 1.119565 ┆ 0.25     │
└───────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

